# compositeCollection DataContext false warning, renaming issue

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, compositecollection

I try to bind a ListBox.ItemsSource to a CompositeCollection containing three CollectionContainers. Each CollectionContainer is bound to a ObservableCollection in my ViewModel.

Because the CompositeCollection does not know my DataContext, i set the Source to a "Proxy" which is a FrameworkElement that knows my DataContext.

```
 <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Dampings, Source={x:Reference Proxy}}" />
 <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Angles, Source={x:Reference Proxy}}" />
 <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Selectors, Source={x:Reference Proxy}}" />
```

This works as expected at runtime, althought it does show a warning at design time on DataContext:
**Cannot resolve Property 'DataContext' in data context of type 'object'.**

Is there a way to solve this designtime issue as the renaming is not applied to my Bindings as the designer cann't resolve them properly?